# MobileFirst SQL adapter raising an error

Tags: oracle, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Sometimes we are receiving following error while calling sql adapter

> ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called.

All objects are valid /compiled and available in oracle DB.

If we change any package or procedure on oracle database we receive that error.  So the question is: Do we need to re-deploy that SQL adapter which calls that database object again?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your connection is holding on to a pointer to a procedure that no longer exists in RAM because it was recompiled.

I have seen this for many years and you can recreate this on the fly.

1. Call an Oracle Procedure
2. Recompile that procedure
3. Call it again you will get "could not find program unit being called."
4. Call it again and it will work.

**If you closed the connection after #2** and then opened the connection and called the procedure you would never get that error.

After you make the call to that proc and you are done, close out your connection before calling it again.

Comment: Thanks, This is how we can do on oracle side but how it would be done through Mobilefirst sql Adapter, this is what main issue is ? How to close the connection before calling it again through mobilefirst sql adapter ?

Comment: MichealSmith: I looked at that SQL Adapter documentation, and was very supervised that I saw no open / close connection, but their JAVA adapter has it. I know the close / open resolves this issue, you may want to contact IBM to ask how to cycle the connection.